# What is a pseudo file system in Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems

could somebody clarify what the meaning `pseudo file system` means and how is it different to a regular `file system` from different point views (users/processes/apps) .

Comment: Could you provide some more context? Maybe check out [how to ask good  questions](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If that is the case here is your answer: https://linux.die.net/man/5/proc In case it's that easy consider using a search engine using your keywords.

Comment: Where have you seen this term? It's not clear @aeid else we wouldn't be asking. I'm *betting* this is a homework question.

Comment: `proc` is not the only pseudo file system , there is `dev` , `sys` ..  , now what is it ?

Comment: You use those terms on your favorite search engine? If you actually read the explanation about what proc is you would understand what makes it a pseudo file system and you would be able to do some more research whenever that is the general understanding. If you want to get actual help you should check your attitude and be less condescending. In addition you still should check [how to ask a good question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand why this isn't one.

Comment: Relevant information from Wikipedia (which calls them "synthetic file systems"): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_file_system

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A pseudo file system maintains information about the currently running system.

This information doesn't persist across reboots. It exists while the system in running only in RAM; in Window this would be the `HKLM`.

In linux `/dev` this includes things like `/dev/tty#` `/dev/ttyS#` they indicate devices as they are connected and they be created dynamically.

`/sys` shows a representation of the physical devices in the machine.

`/proc` maintain a lot of info about the current control set.

Example: `free` command is just importing info from `/proc/meminfo` file.

Answer (score 13):

'Pseudo-' means false, pretend. So "pseudo-filesystem" means a filesystem that doesn't have *actual* files – rather, it has virtual entries that the filesystem itself makes up on the spot.

For example, `/proc` on many OSes is a procfs which dynamically generates directories for every process. Similarly, `/sys` on Linux generates files and directories to represent hardware layouts. There are FUSE-based pseudo-filesystems for a *lot* of things.

`/dev` may be a real filesystem (just a subdirectory of `/`), or a virtual pseudo-filesystem (e.g. devfs), or a middle point such as Linux devtmpfs (which is a full in-memory filesystem but still creates device nodes out of nowhere).